# Prevent click into {{input}} component from propagating/bubbling up (ember)

Tags: ember.js, onclick, components, event-bubbling

I have an `{{input}}` inside of an element that itself has an action.
**How do I prevent clicking into the input from triggering the click event on the parent element?**

1. I have tried `bubbles=false`.
2. I have also tried extending `{{input}}` and in the extended input I caught the click event and called `event.preventDefault()`

**Please try my test case**: https://ember-twiddle.com/a2cee9abd63a7400124e2745a7820cf8?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

Example hbs:

```html
<div {{action "alert"}}>
  I don't want the click into the input to trigger the div's onlick. Help!<br/>
  {{input bubbles=false}}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please put the exact code you tried for second options ?. I tried it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define component say `my-input` which extends `Ember.TextField` and define `click` function and `return false` to prevent bubbling.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  click(){
    console.log('click my input');
    return false;
  }
});
```

For my-input component, you dont need to define anything to handle click event while including the component. you can just say `{{my-input }}`

Here is the working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/69764475967eda29f7a58a61efd6a436?numColumns=2&openFiles=components.my-input.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-input.hbs)

Comment: I didn't try `return false;` Thanks for the help.